# Nifi: using zookeeper with SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I have Nifi cluster with one zookeeper node and five Nifi node. I want to have SSL encryption from the zookeeper server to the Nifi client.
Reading from the [Nifi documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#securing_zookeeper), it says:

> Support for SSL in ZooKeeper is being actively developed and is expected to be available in the 3.5.x release version.

The new zookeeper 3.5.3-beta have SSL capabilities.
I installed zookeeper 3.5.3 but I am unable to secure the connection it with SSL: I am getting NotSslRecordException

How can I run Nifi with a secure zookeeper using SSL?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It requires more than just running ZooKeeper 3.5.x. There is code in NiFi that uses the ZooKeeper client and that code is not based on the 3.5.x client, so there is no way for NiFi to make a SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you also need to setup Zookeeper to use the SSL security for example

```
zookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location="/path/to/your/keystore"
zookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password="keystore_password"
zookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location="/path/to/your/truststore"
zookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password="truststore_password"
```

Full docummentation here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide