# NiFi to Zookeeper SSL Connection

Tags: ssl, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I have a requirement to secure the connection between NiFi and a (non-embedded) Zookeeper cluster. From the [documentation here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#securing_zookeeper) it mentions that it is being worked on in Zookeeper version 3.5.x. However, we are now on version 3.6.1 and I have got SSL working between Zookeeper and Kafka so I know it works.

It seems that the issue was that, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053248/nifi-using-zookeeper-with-ssl), the Zookeeper client code in NiFi was not built on a version supporting SSL.

However, the post is now over 2 years old and Zookeeper 3.5.x has been and gone. My question is; has the Zookeeper client code in NiFi been updated to a version that supports SSL and, if yes, how can I implement it?

Thank you in advance,

Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple Jiras related to this and some PRs open for this work.

- [NIFI-7203](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7203) - Add support for Zookeeper TLS

  - [NIFI-7401](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7401) - Add Zookeeper client TLS to CuratorLeaderElectionManager
  - [NIFI-7357](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7357) - Make Zookeeper TLS properties available via nifi.properties
  - [NIFI-7356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7356) - Enable TLS for embedded Zookeeper when NiFi has TLS enabled
- [NIFI-7124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7124) - Improve experience configuring Zookeeper to support TLS
- [NIFI-7115](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7115) - Add Zookeeper TLS configuration to Administration Guide

I think the short answer to your question is that the complete functionality is not available in an integrated way out of the box right now, but through a combination of setting Java arguments, you should be able to achieve this on a recent version of NiFi (see [PR 4092](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/4092) for instructions via the rendered Admin Guide doc changes). You can follow the specific Jiras above to be kept apprised of new developments.